# How to convert Json object to Jquery Array?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am getting Year and 'NoOfOrders' from a Web Method through ajax call. 
I want to convert Json object to array so that I can plot using jqbargraph.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myArray = [];
    $("[id$=btnSubmit]").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Charts.aspx/GetOrderCount",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var OrdersInfo = data.d;
                $.each(OrdersInfo, function (index, order) {
                    myArray.push(order.OrderYear, order.OrderCount);
                });
            }
        });
        $('#divChart').jqbargraph({
            data: myArray,
            position: 'bottom',
            animate: false
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So what's the problem? What isn't working and what error messages are you seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to push an Array, instead of separate values into `myArray`:

```
$.each(OrdersInfo, function (index, order) {
      myArray.push([order.OrderYear, order.OrderCount]);
});
```